# How to know when a method in a class is being executed

Tags: c#, .net, time, execution

I'm trying to write a log to monitor the execution time of a method for our application. Is it possible to know when a method in a class is being executed without using Aspect-oriented programming.

I don't want to go into every method to write a log there so I hope someone faced this issue and can give me some suggestion.

Updated: I'm writing a SharePoint application using .Net 3.5

Comment: Which .Net version are you using?

Comment: Hi danish, I'm using .Net 3.5

Comment: I see you are doing SharePoint application. I have no clue how that works. Can you take a look at profiling and performance analysis in Visual Studio if that helps you?

Comment: Not the cleanest method, but will kinda work fitter quick and dirty, you could use stopwatch and write out timestamps to your log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, without AOP or directly logging code injections the only way is a [profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384493%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#profiling_api).
I wouldn't choose that way for one-time task, it isn't easy.

Answer (score 0):

Try using breakpoints. Press F10 on the space at the left side of the method, and from there, the debugging starts, where you'd be able to see value and property change after its execution.

Comment: Well, I need to write a log file because I will put my application into a test environment to simulate the real scenario of the production environment. We need to ensure it can run with around 1000 requests per minute.

Answer (score 0):

Addtional to @Dennis answer, I think [System.Diagnostic.Debug](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is a choice to know when your method is executed beside Aspect-oriented programing. However, you need to turn on **Debug** build flag, or supplying argument in csc.exe

```
/define:DEBUG
```

Answer (score 0):

in sp 2010 you can turn on developer dashboard (on dev stage only for safety)
this will give you abreakdown of calls and times

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg512103(v=office.14).aspx